# Why is the decay $\eta'\rightarrow \gamma + \gamma$ suppressed?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model

So the $\eta$ meson's dominant decay mode is $\eta \rightarrow \gamma + \gamma$ whereas the dominant mode for $\eta'$ is $\rho+\gamma $ or $\eta + \pi+\pi$.

Why does it not decay to two photons more readily, the only thing I can think of is charge conjugation but I am not sure?

Comment: Did you actually compare/contrast their actual 2γ decay rates instead of BRs? Did you contrast their masses and *full widths*!? The 500lb gorilla in the room is strong decays itching to swamp everything *if only  they could*.

Comment: aah, so the decay rate into $\gamma\gamma $ is the same its just that the heavier one has more decays and the ones listed above have some strong elements?

Comment: yes....  the EM decays  estimated from BR $times\Gamma$ are roughly of the same order of magnitude, and phase space accounts for the $\eta '$ slight enhancement...